# Is it possible to log-in a container (apache) with Jenkins pipeline, I tried the following:

Tags: docker, jenkins

pipeline {
  agent any
    options {
       timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
       disableConcurrentBuilds()  }
    stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
       steps {
         script {
                 checkout([
                         $class: 'GitSCM',
                         branches: [[name: "origin/master"]],
                         userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/mmmmmmmmm.git']]
                 ])
          } } }

```
        stage('Cleanup') {
          steps {
            echo 'Starting the Pipeline'
            sh 'docker rm -f $(docker ps --all --quiet) || true'
            sh 'docker rmi -f $(docker images --quiet) || true'
         }
       }
    stage('build') {
      steps {
            sh 'docker build -t test --no-cache .'
      }
    }

    stage('Run')  {
      steps {
            sh 'docker run -d --name test -p 80:80 test '

      }
    }

    stage('Login')  {
      steps {
            sh 'docker container exec -it test /bin/bash '
            sh 'ls -ltr'
```

}}}}

Error:  docker container exec -it test /bin/bash
the input device is not a TTY

And how to run curl command for the jenkins server port 80?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the `curl` command with `exec` like below.

```
sh "docker exec containerName /bin/bash -c 'curl http://jenkins-server:80'"
```